# SecurityProvider service class name for OAMIDAsserter is not specified

Tags: weblogic11g, nodemanager

weblogic 10.3.6

Admin server failed to start using script after connected to nodemanager using nmStart('AdminServer')

Messages related in adminserver.log below:

> ####<Sep 20, 2023 9:23:00 AM MYT>   <sso.domain.com>  <[ACTIVE]
> ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1695172980261>  <The following exception has occurred:
>
> com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: com.bea.common.engine.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:097533]SecurityProvider service class name for OAMIDAsserter is not specified.
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:365)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:315)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.lookupService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:257)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServicesImpl.getService(ServicesImpl.java:72)
> at weblogic.security.service.internal.WLSIdentityServiceImpl.initialize(WLSIdentityServiceImpl.java:46)
> at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.initializeServiceEngine(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:299)
> at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.initialize(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:221)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.InitializeServiceEngine(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1790)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:446)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.loadRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:841)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealms(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:871)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1034)
> at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:894)
> at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
> at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
> Caused By: com.bea.common.engine.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:097533]SecurityProvider service class name for OAMIDAsserter is not specified.
> at com.bea.common.security.internal.legacy.service.SecurityProviderImpl.init(SecurityProviderImpl.java:42)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:363)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:315)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.lookupService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:257)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServicesImpl.getService(ServicesImpl.java:72)
> at weblogic.security.service.internal.WLSIdentityServiceImpl.initialize(WLSIdentityServiceImpl.java:46)
> at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.initializeServiceEngine(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:299)
> at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.initialize(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:221)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.InitializeServiceEngine(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1790)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:446)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.loadRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:841)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealms(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:871)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1034)
> at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:894)
> at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
> at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>
> > 
>
> ####<Sep 20, 2023 9:23:00 AM MYT>   <sso.domain.com>  <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1695172980264>  <The realm "myrealm" failed to be loaded: weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceException: com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: com.bea.common.engine.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:097533]SecurityProvider service class name for OAMIDAsserter is not specified..
> weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceException: com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: com.bea.common.engine.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:097533]SecurityProvider service class name for OAMIDAsserter is not specified.
> at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.initializeServiceEngine(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:341)
> at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.initialize(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:220)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.InitializeServiceEngine(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1789)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:443)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.loadRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:841)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealms(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:870)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1034)
> at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:894)
> at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
> at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
> Caused By: com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: com.bea.common.engine.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:097533]SecurityProvider service class name for OAMIDAsserter is not specified.
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:365)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:315)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.lookupService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:257)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServicesImpl.getService(ServicesImpl.java:72)
> at weblogic.security.service.internal.WLSIdentityServiceImpl.initialize(WLSIdentityServiceImpl.java:46)
> at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.initializeServiceEngine(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:299)
> at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.initialize(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:221)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.InitializeServiceEngine(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1790)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:446)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.loadRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:841)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealms(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:871)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1034)
> at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:894)
> at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
> at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
> Caused By: com.bea.common.engine.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:097533]SecurityProvider service class name for OAMIDAsserter is not specified.
> at com.bea.common.security.internal.legacy.service.SecurityProviderImpl.init(SecurityProviderImpl.java:42)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:363)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:315)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.lookupService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:257)
> at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServicesImpl.getService(ServicesImpl.java:72)
> at weblogic.security.service.internal.WLSIdentityServiceImpl.initialize(WLSIdentityServiceImpl.java:46)
> at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.initializeServiceEngine(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:299)
> at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.initialize(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:221)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.InitializeServiceEngine(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1790)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:446)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.loadRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:841)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealms(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:871)
> at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1034)
> at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:894)
> at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
> at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

Any idea what else I should try?

- verified it failed to start using script after connected to nodemanager using nmStart('AdminServer')
- verified manual connect to nodemanager using wlst.sh successful
- verified StartScriptName=startWebLogic.sh & StartScriptEnabled=true in nodemanager.propreties